# HTML zooms in/out in iOS when open/closing a menu

Tags: jquery, css, ios, html, mobile-safari

I'm working on a mobile site using a menu similar to Facebook's, and other than mobile Safari everything is working out swell. The problem is once I open the menu on an iPhone, the rest of the content scales down to fit on the screen, then scales back up when the menu is closed.

To make it extra fun, this only occurs when running in the browser - if you bookmark it to the home screen, the content doesn't resize. It also doesn't resize on the iPad, just the iPhone.

I have a simplified version of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/261/

If you have an iPhone, you can see the problem running here: http://tfklabs.com/clients/mypr/

I've tried several things, including setting #right div to position:fixed instead of position:absolute. It actually works, but then the user is unable to scroll the content of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to scale your div, you need to slide it inside its parent. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/262/. Ive made some changes in your html structure and css as well.

Comment: That fixed the scaling, but it disabled vertical scrolling. Adding
`overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

fixed that part and gave it momentum again. Thanks!